# I have some columns in my pandas dataframe in nested JSON format. I need to remove all the junk and keep the values with key:"name"

Tags: python, json, pandas

> This is my current attempt but it gives me an error : "JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 32751 (char 32750)"

```
def parse_col_json(column, key):

for index,i in zip(movies_df.index,movies_df[column].apply(json.loads)):
      list1=[]
      for j in range(len(i)):
        list1.append((i[j][key]))
      movies_df.loc[index,column]=str(list1)
parse_col_json('genres', 'name')
parse_col_json('spoken_languages', 'name')
```

> My dataframe looks like this:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/csWx3.png)

Comment: That error looks like a malformed JSON string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Do you know how I could remove that string?